# Make multiple iframe resizable in webpage

Tags: jquery, iframe, jquery-ui-resizable

How to make multiple iframe resizable? i am able to make one iframe resizable using **jqueryUI library**.

i have try as follow :

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Resizable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <style>

#iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;    

  background: #eee ;

}

#resizable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;


}

  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $('#resizable').resizable({
      start: function(event, ui) {
        $('iframe').css('pointer-events','none');
         },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $('iframe').css('pointer-events','auto');
      }
  });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="resizable">
  <iframe src="test.html" id="iframe">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

above code work fine for me. but idont know how can i make multiple iframe resizable.  i have two iframe as in below image. i want make both of them to resizable.
**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/butani_vijay010/KRTHe/)**

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: have same problem .do you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to make multiple frame by default if you declare iframe code once multiple frame automatically comes one inside another, just write "something code"

Comment: Any example? can you share ?